# Haskell Interview Questions

Tags: haskell

Since this hasn't been asked any where I could find on SO,and since I may be hiring a haskell dev soon I thought I would bring this up..

What would be some detailed verbal questions to ask that would demonstrate a strong working knowledge of haskell. I can think of a few good questions and coding projects, but it would really help to see what other people think.

Comment: Perhaps this question is better suited for http://programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: A good question for any language: "What's the worst wart in language X?". Downsides: you must know language X to evaluate the quality of their answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually ask interview questions starting with easy and going to hard. Eventually you get to a question hard enough to make the candidate fail or at least sweat, and then you get to see how they handle the pressure.

So for Haskell, you might go with:

- easy: generate a list of primes
- medium: write a function that gives the nth Fibonacci number
- hard: demonstrate the use of a Monad

Comment: i like this approach and the examples are good. They show that they read tutorials on the web i guess, maybe a Very Hard at the end to see how they would solve a problem related to the problems were trying to solve

Answer (score 1):

One of my favourites is the following:

> Write a function to sort a list by frequencies of the elements. The element that appears in the list least frequently should go first and the element that is the most frequent should go last. For example, [3,2,1,2] should be ordered as [3,1,2,2].

I like questions like this since they allow the applicant to provide a simple solution and still enable discussion on more efficient alternatives.

Naturally, you'd want to ask more complicated ones later in the interview.

Comment: The most frequent should go first and the most frequent should go last? A kind of split-personality list, then, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

"Explain what you see as the relative advantages and disadvantages of `Monad`, `Applicative` and `Arrow`."

"Explain what you see as the relative advantages and disadvantages of using type families and dependent types."

But mainly, you're right to want to see some code, written there and then, and you need to ask questions about how they would develop their solutions in various situations.

Comment: ..and of course general questions to find out what they're like:

Comment: Ask "Why would you like to leave your current/previous job?" to find out if they can't resist being intolerant or grumpy. Ask "You'll have come across plenty of other developers; some are really good, some are rubbish. What makes a really good developer?" to find out if they can work with your team and what they think you're looking for. Ask "We're committed to high quality software. What is high for you and how do you ensure it happens?"  to find out what they think is important. Ask "What makes a good colleague?" to know their attitudes. Don't employ people who use the opportunity to moan!